# VirtualBox in VirtualBox CPU core usage

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, multi-core

Background: I am attempting to run a VirtualBox VM within a VirtualBox VM. The first host machine is running atop an Intel 4670k, with Intel Virtualization Technology enabled, with 4 total cores available. The OS is Windows 7 without hyper-v installed. The second guest OS is a debian based distro with all 4 cores made available to it from within the VirtualBox settings. I am attempting to run a second VM (also VirtualBox) from within the first VM, with exactly 2 cores made available to it (Half of the total available).

The Question: While attempting to alter the number of cores available for the second VM, I am incapable of changing the value. So the question is, is it possible to have (2) virtualized environments running while utilizing the multi-core technology on an Intel Platform?

I have read of several issues where Microsoft's hyper-v "takes over" all available cores from within Windows, so any other virtualization application running on top of Windows will not have them available. I wonder if this is something similar to what I am facing from within the Debian environment. Bonus points to those who can explain how VirtualBox actually knows if these cores are available or not, I am somewhat new to virtualization so resources are always appreciated.

The output of "cat /proc/cpuinfo" does properly display all 4 CPU's (0-3)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If Hyper-V isn’t enabled on the host OS then it’s not possible for it to take over, and you would know if it was installed, because VirtualBox would complain about it

Comment: Hyper-v is not installed on the guest OS, however I should be clear that my mention of Hyper-v was to potentially provide evidence that my concerns that I am unable to utilize multiple cores on more than one VM at one time may be true.

Comment: I wasn’t even aware that VirtualBox supported nested virtualization.  I am even shocked it’s worked.  Your inability to modify the nested VM has nothing to do with Hyper-V

Comment: It doesn't evidently, and I jumped the gun focusing on the wrong thing, thanks for clearing that up. Any suggestions for a hypervisor that DOES support nested virtualization, specifically with the needs that I listed above?

Comment: Hyper-V actually does.  However, you are running Windows 7, which doesn’t support Hyper-V.

Comment: VMware Workstation supports nested virtualization.